# XCode includes duplicate Launch images in API

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

When I try to build an iOS app from unity it selects to use Asset Catalog for the launch images.

When I try to build the app the API looks large there are duplicate images with different names for example

```
"*LaunchImage-Landscape@2x~ipad*"
```

and

```
"`LaunchImage-700-Landscape~ipad`"
```

are exactly the same just with a different name.

Does this increase the API size? If it does can I remove the duplicate and use only one of these?

Comment: App size naturally increases with each file. Whether you need them all and which ones you can get away with depends. Here's more info on launch images: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html